# Scale Multiple Paths According to Single Part Dimensions

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, line-art, transform, scale

How can one scale both a rectangle and a circle--both being selected--so that the circle is scaled appropriately according to what I want to specify the rectangle's width to be?

Comment: Do I just have to measure what the width is now, then scale to the percentage of the ratio of what I want over what I have already?

Answer (score 1):

For precision, if you need the objects to be a specific width....

[image]

[image]

If you want to scale by a percentage.

[image]

**You can also perform math functions in dimension fields.** (+ plus, - minus, * multiply, and / divide) So if you know your square is 100pt wide and you want the circle to be 80% of 100pts, you could input `100*.8` into the Width field (100pts times .8 = 80% of 100):

[image]

Hit enter and the value will be calculated (80pts)